# Start longtable on new page without \afterpage

Tags: floats, longtable, afterpage

I have a `longtable` that only shows the header and the first row on the first page, and then proceeds to show the rest over the next two pages. I want to make the `longtable` start on the next page.

I cannot use `\afterpage` because it messes up the table numbering for some reason. (Table number goes from `5.1` to `.1`) and the numbering is necessary as this is for a thesis.

If I can get the table to start at the following page or get it to have some sort of floating behavior, that would be great.

If the above is not possible, then how can I use `\afterpage` so that it preserves the section numbering?

```
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|cc|cc|}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Lipsum}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Lipsum}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{A}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{B}} \\ \cline{3-6} 
    &  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{1}} & \textbf{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{1}} & \textbf{2} \\ \hline
    \endhead
    \caption{This is a caption}\label{tab:ch5_rm}
    \endfoot
    \caption*{(Table \ref{tab:ch5_rm} continued)}
    \endlastfoot
    Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum & Lipsum & Lipsum & Lipsum & Lipsum \\ \hline
    % Imagine a bunch more of these.
\end{longtable}
```

Edit: I apologize if I was unclear. Here is a screenshot showing how the `longtable` looks across two pages (I blurred out some sensitive information).

[image: Screenshot]

The top half is the end of one page, while the bottom half is the start of the next page. As you can see, the table has only one row on the first page.

My problem is that I cannot move the `longtable` to the second page, similar to how the `\begin{table}\end{table}` floats to the next page if there is insufficient space.

Note: `\clearpage` does move it to the next page, but it lacks the `float` property that I'm looking for (i.e., Elements below the table will not move up to fill the empty space). So it could be helpful in some situations, but it's not the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: you haven't really given enough information nor provided a usable example, but perhaps you just want to use `\clearpage` before `\begin{longtable}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I edited the question with a screenshot. I apologize for not being able to provide a usable example, but making one from scratch would take more time than I have at the moment. If this is still not enough information, I'll see if I can whip something up when I am able.

Comment: well as I say use `\clearpage` probably just before `\subsection{radomised manipulation}` longtables don't float.

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete small document (Minimal Working Example: MWE) which reproduce your problem. Table can have dummy content.

Comment: Why is the caption placed after the header material? It would appear that you’re the sing the `caption` package. If this is the case, please show us any and all `\cationsetup` directives.

Comment: `longtable` environments are *not* floats (in the LaTeX-specific sense of the term).